# Java- Keylistener on Tab doesnt work

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, keylistener, keyevent

I've got a GUI with several elements on which i just tab through and on the last element i specified (which is the text area) i want it to make an event if i press tab.

It works perfectly fine as i wrote my code with the enter button but not with the tab button and i can't find out why.

My GUI window:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/do8Y5.jpg]

Here is my code:

```
textArea_beschreibung.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_TAB){
            String dauervar = input_dauer.getText ();  //auslesen von benutzername
            String beschreibungvar = textArea_beschreibung.getText ();  //auslesen von benutzername
            String projektvar = (String)comboBox_projekt.getSelectedItem();
            String aktivitvar = (String)comboBox_aktivitaet.getSelectedItem();

            String datumvar = input_datum.getText ();  
            SimpleDateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            Date date = null;
            try {
                date = df1.parse(datumvar);
            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            long epoch = date.getTime();
            String numberAsStringUnixTImestamp = String.valueOf(epoch / 1000);

            String [ ] datenarray = {"a","b","c","d","e","f"};  

            datenarray[0] = numberAsStringUnixTImestamp;
            datenarray[1] = dauervar;   
            datenarray[2] = beschreibungvar;    
            datenarray[3] = projektvar; 
            datenarray[4] = aktivitvar; 
            datenarray[5] = usernamevar;    

            String JsonArray = "{ \"" + "datum" + "\":\"" + datenarray[0] + "\", \"" + "dauer" + "\":\"" + datenarray[1] + "\", \"" + "beschreibung" + "\":\"" + datenarray[2] + "\", \"" + "projektname" + "\":\"" + datenarray[3] + "\", \"" + "kategorie" + "\":\"" + datenarray[4] + "\", \"" + "username" + "\":\"" + datenarray[5] + "\" }";

            input_datum.setText(reportDate);
            if(check_datum.isSelected()){
                CustomDateFinal[0] = datumvar;
                input_datum.setText(CustomDateFinal[0]);

            }                               
            input_dauer.setText(USERDefTimeJSON);
            textArea_beschreibung.setText("");
            comboBox_projekt.requestFocus();


            try {
                SimplePingPong.httpRequestVoid(JsonArray,"unused","werte");
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: When you press the TAB key - do you still get the event and just `e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_TAB` fails to return true? Waht ist the value of getKeyCode then?

Comment: when i press tab it just jumps to the next element. I#m not sure either but i did it the same way with the VK_ENTER key and it works perfectly. The text area is also no ,onger present in the traversal policy but still jumps to the next element

Comment: OK, look into setDefaultFocusTraversalKeys of java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager. You'll have to redefine this set to avoid having TAB act as the forward traversal function key. (As a user, I would be somewhat irritated by the behaviour you want to implement.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> on the last element i specified (which is the text area) i want it to make an event if i press tab.

The Tab key is handled by the text area. The default Action is to insert a tab character into the text area.

To restore default tabbing logic you can use any of the following:

```
/*
    This is my understanding of how tabbing works. The focus manager
    recognizes the following default KeyStrokes for tabbing:

    forwards:  TAB or Ctrl-TAB
    backwards: Shift-TAB or Ctrl-Shift-TAB

    In the case of JTextArea, TAB and Shift-TAB have been removed from
    the defaults which means the KeyStroke is passed to the text area.
    The TAB KeyStroke inserts a tab into the Document. Shift-TAB seems
    to be ignored.

    This example shows different approaches for tabbing out of a JTextArea
*/
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TextAreaTab extends JFrame
{
    public TextAreaTab()
    {
        Container contentPane = getContentPane();
        contentPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        contentPane.add( nullTraversalKeys() );
        contentPane.add( writeYourOwnAction() );
        contentPane.add( useKeyListener() );
        contentPane.add( addTraversalKeys() );
    }

    //  Reset the text area to use the default tab keys.
    //  This is probably the best solution.

    private JComponent nullTraversalKeys()
    {
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(3, 30);

        textArea.setText("Null Traversal Keys\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9");
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( textArea );

        textArea.setFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.FORWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS, null);
        textArea.setFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.BACKWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS, null);

        return scrollPane;
    }

    //  Replace the Tab Actions. A little more complicated but this shows
    //  how to create a custom Action so you have full control.

    private JComponent writeYourOwnAction()
    {
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(3, 30);
        textArea.setText("Write Your Own Tab Actions\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9");
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( textArea );

        InputMap im = textArea.getInputMap();
        KeyStroke tab = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("TAB");
        textArea.getActionMap().put(im.get(tab), new TabAction(true));
        KeyStroke shiftTab = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("shift TAB");
        im.put(shiftTab, shiftTab);
        textArea.getActionMap().put(im.get(shiftTab), new TabAction(false));

        return scrollPane;
    }

    //  Use a KeyListener
    //  (not recommended, since Swing provides newer and better API's)

    private JComponent useKeyListener()
    {
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(3, 30);
        textArea.setText("Use Key Listener\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9");
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( textArea );

        textArea.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter()
        {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
            {
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_TAB)
                {
                    e.consume();
                    KeyboardFocusManager.
                        getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().focusNextComponent();
                }

                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_TAB
                &&  e.isShiftDown())
                {
                    e.consume();
                    KeyboardFocusManager.
                        getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().focusPreviousComponent();
                }
            }
        });

        return scrollPane;
    }

    //  Add Tab and Shift-Tab KeyStrokes back as focus traversal keys.
    //  Seems more complicated then just using null, but at least
    //  it shows how to add a KeyStroke as a focus traversal key.

    private JComponent addTraversalKeys()
    {
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(3, 30);
        textArea.setText("Add Traversal Keys\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9");
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( textArea );

        Set set = new HashSet( textArea.getFocusTraversalKeys(
            KeyboardFocusManager.FORWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS ) );
        set.add( KeyStroke.getKeyStroke( "TAB" ) );
        textArea.setFocusTraversalKeys(
            KeyboardFocusManager.FORWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS, set );

        set = new HashSet( textArea.getFocusTraversalKeys(
            KeyboardFocusManager.BACKWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS ) );
        set.add( KeyStroke.getKeyStroke( "shift TAB" ) );
        textArea.setFocusTraversalKeys(
            KeyboardFocusManager.BACKWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS, set );

        return scrollPane;
    }

    class TabAction extends AbstractAction
    {
        private boolean forward;

        public TabAction(boolean forward)
        {
            this.forward = forward;
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if (forward)
                tabForward();
            else
                tabBackward();
        }

        private void tabForward()
        {
            KeyboardFocusManager manager = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager();
            manager.focusNextComponent();
        }

        private void tabBackward()
        {
            KeyboardFocusManager manager = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager();
            manager.focusPreviousComponent();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        }
        catch (Exception e) { }
        TextAreaTab frame = new TextAreaTab();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I question actually doing all the processing when the tab key is pressed. The functionality of the Tab key should just be to move focus to the next component.

If the user wants to process all the data on the form, then you should have some kind of "Process Data" button that the user can click. Maybe this button is right after the text area.